# How can I make a chain of HoC appear as a single component in React DevTools?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-devtools, react-native-debugger

I'd like to have my HoCs do as little as possible for what they need.  (e.g. `withI18n`, `withStyled`, `withNativeFontFamily`)

So if I had something like

```
const MyText = withI18n(withStyled(withNativeFontFamily(Text)));
```

I'd like to show in React DevTools as

```
<MyText>
  <Text>
</MyText>
```

Instead I get something like this which is one component per HoC.

[image]

Is it possible to do without the obvious refactor your HoC chain into a single method.  Because though that may be easy to do, setting up the types would be hard.

Comment: I don't see any existing functions doing that at this moment

Comment: You want hide part of tree. It is impossible. This is how HOCs works and this is one of reasons why hooks were presented

Comment: @DmitriyKudasov you can make that comment an answer I'll check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want hide part of tree. It is impossible. This is how HOCs works and this is one of reasons why hooks were presented.